# How to make self closing tags to open and close tags with null values? web api

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

i want to ask how to convert self closing tag to ope and end tags in web api, i have searched in web site and it told me the self closing tag is the better way to do it, but i want to make my tags look like same as other column, is there any possible to make open and close tags?

My code:

```
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            List<TestClass> draft = new List<TestClass>();
            string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
            string sqlquery = "SELECT UserID, Name, Mobile, Access, Date From tbluser";
            sqlconn.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    draft.Add(new TestClass()
                    {
                        UserId = sdr.GetString(0),
                        Name = sdr.GetString(1),
                        Mobile = sdr.GetString(2),
                        Age = sdr.GetInt32(3),
                        Date = sdr.GetDateTime(4)
                    });
                }
            return Ok(draft);
        }
```

this shows in chrome:

```
<ArrayOfUser xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<User>
<UserId>1</UserId>
<Name>Emily</Name>
<Mobile>76314951</Mobile>
<Age>21</Age>
<Date>2021-10-22T03:11:00</Date>
</User>
<User>
<UserId>2</UserId>
<Name>Peter</Name>
<Mobile>23489104</Mobile>
<Age>45</Age>
<Date>2022-06-05T17:21:00</Date>
</User>
```

Comment: XML specification allows for closing tags to either have or not to have tag names.  The Net library for empty tags does not show the tag names (Uses <tag/>).  There is not option in Net library to include tags name when null.

Comment: so which mean i am using asp.net, and there is no way to use open and close tags, right?

Comment: Your example fails to show any empty elements, using either self-closing tags or open/close tags.  Regardless, there is no difference, so you shouldn't waste time worrying about it, and you definitely should never write code that depends on one form vs the other.  Any code that does depend on the difference is broken and should be fixed, not catered to.

Comment: It is right.  The XML requirements allow both methods.   Net library has no options to change format.